# Seam Issues when Posing Model

Tags: mesh, vertices, makehuman

Good to be here. Am just getting used to this lovely app. Guess I have ver. 2.83. I have learned how to rig bones and fix bones, add textures, not to mention a handful of other things related to import/export plugins. I have hit a snag though which my powers of play have yet to fiddle out a nice tune.

[image]

Also made a screencapture MP4 so you can see in real-time how when I pose my model, the neck area begins to tear. I am sure there is an easy fix for this. But until now, it has evaded me. Hope it ok to post mega links. Was not sure how to upload/show a video here.

https://mega.nz/file/dRMzFCQb#0qZZ-XO2w9uS92gZZrFFIy7h6FiUTieYP2XqMgGFP6k

EDIT: Thanks to Ben, I was able to merge the head and neck meshes using a careful selection of all verts in at the seams, then punch m, then By Distance. Unfortunately, while there is no more tearing, the model now gets garbled at the seams when I try to pose it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help, but make sure in weight paint mode, the side of the neck that is not moving is not blue. If it is blue it will not be affected by the bone so you can then weight paint onto it and make it affected by the bone. I hope this help!

Comment: OK, so its not that the vertices need to be welded or joined, it is simply I need to select each bone around that area, and weight paint it to NOT move when the bone does?

Comment: I think what is wrong, is that the bone is not affecting that area. You want the other side of the split to move, but I think that the problem is that the bone doesn't move that area. In order to make it so the bone does the effect that area, you have to go into weight paint mode and make sure that when you click on the bone in the vertex group area, you need to make sure that the other side of the neck isn't blue. if it is, it will not be affected and you will need to paint over it with the bone selected in the vertex group tab. I hope that this is helpful!

Comment: Yes, it would probably be golf to merge them together. In edit mode, you can merge vertices together by selecting the vertices you want to merge and pressing m.

Comment: Not golf to merge them, good to merge them. I can't find an edit button on the comments.

Comment: Yeah, I think it(the edit button) times out after a few minutes. Thank you very much for your suggestions Ben! How I fixed the tearing was to do as you said. Select the area where the tear was happening and punch m on my keyboard, then By Distance. That merged just the vertices I needed to get my mesh solid. The new issue I have now in posing is the area around the merges seems to garble out. I tried weight painting those areas based on different adjacent bones and had some luck with cleanup. But not all.